# Почему ctypes медленный?

Tags: python, ctypes

Простой пример:

```
extern "C"
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        int integer_field;
        char* null_terminated_string;
    };
    __declspec(dllexport) void MyFunc(MyStruct* structure_array, int length);
}
```

Сама функция пуста и ничего не делает:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

__declspec(dllexport) void MyFunc(MyStruct* structure_array, int length)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        // printf("%d", structure_array[i].integer_field);
    }
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import c_char_p, POINTER, c_int, c_float, Structure, WINFUNCTYPE, windll, byref, cast
import time


class MyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = (("integer_field", c_int), ("null_terminated_string", c_char_p))

    def __init__(self, intf, strf):
        super().__init__(intf, strf)

struc_pointer = POINTER(MyStruct)

# или cdll.Load ...
lib = windll.LoadLibrary('x64dll.dll')
MyFunc = lib.MyFunc
MyFunc.restype = None
MyFunc.argtypes = (struc_pointer, c_int)

struc = MyStruct(666, b"satan")
struc2 = MyStruct(777, b"lucky")
lst = [struc, struc2]

TIMES = 10 ** 6

start = time.clock()

my_c_array = (MyStruct * len(lst))(*lst)

for i in range(TIMES):
    MyFunc(my_c_array, len(lst))

print("TOTAL:", time.clock() - start, "sec")
print("1 call:", format(((time.clock() - start) / TIMES) * 10 ** 6, ".3f"), "microsec")

>>> TOTAL: 1.0535024347466948 sec
>>> 1 call: 1.054 microsec
```

Целая микросекунда на вызов? На вызов пустой функции? Что такого сложного происходит в это время и почему время вызова не измеряется в наносекундах?

По-хорошему нужно не кешировать `my_c_array` и перенести в вызов функции:

```
 MyFunc((MyStruct * len(lst))(*lst), len(lst))
```

и тогда при увеличении длины списка все становится неприемлимо плохо.